# Solving the determinant of the adjoint of a matrix.

Tags: matrices, determinant, self-learning

If A is non-singular matrix of order $4\times 4$ and determinant of $Adj(A) =  4$,
then the value of $\left | 2  Adj(3A) \right |$ is ?

To solve this question I began with the knowledge that
$$\ \left | Adj(kA)\right |  = k^{n(n-1)}\  \  \left | A \right |^{n-1} \ \ where\ n\ is\ the\ order\ of\ the\ square\ matrix \ $$

$$  \ \ \ \   ( \ \left | Adj(A)\right | = \left | A \right |^{n-1} \ )$$

Therefore
$$\left | Adj(3A)\right | = 3^{4*3} \  \left | A \right |^{3}  $$

Now when taking a scalar term outside a determinant, it is raised to the power of the order of the matrix.

So in our case  $ \  \left | 2Adj(3A)\right | = 2^{4} \ 3^{12} \  4^{3}  $

Is my solution correct?

Edit: My answer above is not correct lol

I had equated    $ \left | A \right | = 4  \ $ instead of $ \ \left | Adj(A)\right | = 4 \ $ as mentioned by @Semiclassical.

So the answer actually comes up to $ 2^{6} * 3^{12}$

Comment: This would be correct if $|A|=4$. But you're told that $|\text{Adj}(A)|=4$.

Comment: @Semiclassical you are right. So then  $\left  |A \right | = 4^{1/3}$ and so the answer will be $2^{6}* 3^{12}$. Correct?

Comment: That looks right.

Comment: @Semiclassical Thank you